# style guides: lower case titles

Tags: style-guide, letter-case

I've just started at a new company, and I'm trying to set up a style guide for our UI text. I know that for titles, the most common options are

- Title Case
- Sentence case

One of our corporate values relates to humility. There's a belief that **lower case** titles in UI is one way to promote humility.

I'm hoping for a supporting precedent. Is there a UI text style guide that supports lower case titles?

Comment: Not aware of a published precedent, but I worked for an organization that used lowercase as the official style. There were so many problems with it that they had to revert to allowing uppercase letters, and they are now officially sentence case. Problems included acronyms, proper nouns, "childish feeling" on serious subjects.

Comment: Is this belief linking humility and lower case titles internal to your company or is this something you've come across elsewhere?

Comment: Not related to humility, but worked for a company that spelled their name in lowercase. Also issues with legibility and they have since changed to use a capital in their name. I would suggest you find other ways to convey humility such as fonts and branding instead :)

Comment: I would argue that trying to advertise one's own humility isn't very humble at all.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a style guide, but the official style of the revolutionary HfG school of design in Ulm, Germany (1953-1968) was lower case.
"They would write exclusively in lower case, and not for reasons of 'history or linguistic philosophy', as the commentary says, 'but rather for expediency. Upper-case letters are detours for the hand and eye.'"
https://ndion.de/en/spotlight-the-ulm-school-of-design-design-for-millions/

In German, all nouns are capitalized. So a typical German sentence, much like title case, can have many "visual detours".

Removing all capitals does introduce problems for proper names, but also forces consistency and eliminates potential for error. It would also be possible to define lowercase as the corporate identity standard, with the exception of proper names.